# Grab objects near camera

Tags: three.js

I was looking at the `http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_nearestneighbour.html` and had a few questions come up. I see that they use the kdtree to stick all the particles positions and then have a function to determine the nearest particle and color it. Let's say that you have a canvas with around 100 buffered geometries with around 72000 vertices / geometry. The only way I know to do this is that you get the positions of the buffered geometries and then put them into the kdtree to determine the nearest vertice and go from there. This sounds very expensive.

What other way is there to return the objects that are near the camera. Something like how THREE.LOD does it? http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod It has the ability to see how far an object is and render the different levels depending on the setting you inputted.

Answer (score 1):

Define "expensive". The point of the kdtree is to find nearest neighbour elements quickly, its  primary focus is not on saving memory (Although it does everything inplace on a typed array, it's quit cheap in terms of memory already). If you need to save memory you maybe have to find another way.
Yet a typed array with length 21'600'000 is indeed a bit long. I highly doubt you have to have every single vertex in there. Why not have a position reference point for every geometry part? And, if you need to get the vertices associated to that point, a dictionary. Then you can call *myGeometryVertices[ geometryReferencePoint ]*.

Three.LOD works with raycasts. If you have a (few) hundred objects that might work well. If you have hundred thousands or even millions of positions you'll get some troubles. Also if you're not using meshes; you can't raytrace e.g. a particle.

Really just build your own logic with them. None of those two provide a prebuilt perfect-for-all-cases solution.

Comment: Well when I move across the plane, I have objects being dynamically created from incoming data. That would mean I would have to recreate a kdtree with the new items as I move. Raycasts sound like a workable solution to me at the moment. I was under the impression it shoots in one direction. How does it work with raycasting everything in your FOV?

On another note, you seem very knowledgeable. You have answered almost all my questions about THREE.js and has helped me tremendously. If you don't mind, any other way I can chat with you with other questions I have?

Comment: Ah, tricky. Yeah a bad way to do this would be to recreate the entire kdtree every time a new vertex appears ^^ But a good idea might be to seperate your geometry in regions with position reference points. And a region that's still "being built" would simply be always on high resolution. And when the region's complete you build a kdtree for it, since every region would have their own kdtree. But it really depends on your scenario, I'm sure you can come up with something :)

Comment: Thanks. However I just answer questions every now and then when I feel like it and have the time. I doubt you'd get much more out of me when you chat with me. Further on Stackoverflow other people might profit from your case if they have some similar issue. On chat the discussion would just be lost... So I'd tend to say "no" but if you can't let it be: I'm on #three.js on irc.freenode.com, there you'll find me plus several far more knowledgeable people than myself :)

Comment: The problem with using positions is that if I have points that are splined together, I cant really tell if the line is close to me unless I get near the control point.

Comment: Hmm this issue is closed, right? You got some inspiration in IRC if my memory serves